# 'ssh-keygen' - creates ssh key pair but silently skips encrypting the public key. Why?

Tags: ssh, encryption

For example
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "test" -f test -N "1234567890"`
creates a public key beginning with

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNz....
```

instead of

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,....
```

Until recently, I was able to create encrypted keys (as in the example) without problem.

I have already encrypted keys generated earlier, and if I use `ssh-add` to add the key, it will prompt me to enter the password and correctly decrypts and adds it.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is encrypted - it's just not shown in the header.

This can be verified using `ssh-keygen -yf file`. If the key is encrypted you will be prompted for pass phrase. If it's not encrypted you will not be prompted for pass phrase before public key is printed to stdout.

`-y` creates the public key for the corresponding private key in `file`. Here it's used just to verify if the key is encrypted or not, and does not modify the `file` with the private key in any way.

Comment: I see, the private key format has changed.

Comment: Yep, looks that way. If you try to use the key you'll be prompted. `ssh-keygen -y` is simply easiest way of *using* a random key...